# Fire Event every (x) passes in Java?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, i am creating a bukkit plugin which uses this event:

```
public void onCreatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent e) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Inside of the event i need and if statement to fire every (x) amount of time the Creature event has been fired.

For instance if 10 creatures spawned, out of those 10, i would need the if statement to fire 2  times.

Out of the two creatures, 2 of them will get a special characteristic. My issue is, how can i make it so where this statement only fires (x) out of the many times it has been fired?

I have also tried something along the lines of the example below, but ran into some issues:

```
int outOf = Plugin.getConfig().getInt("armourSpawn");
int count = 1;
if(count%outOf==0) {
    // This will fire (x) out of (x) times
}

count++;
```

Basically, the user will chose (x) out of 10 Monsters will have some certain characteristic in the config.

Out of ALL the creatures (that are monsters) that spawn i want a ration of (x) to 10 that have the characteristic.

Comment: What issues did you run into

Comment: @zgc7009 i could never get it to work. Also, it needs to count to 10, instead of intervals of 10.

Comment: Are you saying, you want a counter to go up every time you make a creature? Why not use a global integer/some external counter? Could you give an example of what you want to happen fully, also?

Comment: @SWPhantom Not exactly. I want it so out of every 10 creatures, (x) amount of them get some characteristic. I will chose the characteristic as well as how many out of 10 will be spawned with it.

Comment: I'm probably missing the obvious by why wouldn't you just have two counters? One for special creatures (decremented for each creation of `special creature`) and one for the total count. Each iteration would create a special character until that count reaches zero then it would create the others until it reaches the total needed.

Comment: @JeffWard because the event is fired every time a creature is spawned. I dont know how many will spawn. But out the the many that spawn, i need a ration of (x) to 10 of the to have the special characteristic.

Comment: Could you use Random and get an approximate number of chosen entities that will get special characteristics? If you need PRECISELY X out of N randomly chosen entities, you could also use a Bag structure.

Comment: @SWPhantom how would i do that?

Comment: The completely Random way is easy:
Let's say you want 25% of your entities to spawn with some random feature. You would write Random rand = new Random(); onSpawn{if(rand.nextInt(100) < 25) {specialFeature}}

Comment: @SWPhantom yes, a percentage would be nice. Could you please show me how to implement this in my code and post as an answer?

Comment: Whoever is wanting to close this Question would you please care to discuss why? Ans the reason for the downvote as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better illustrate the Random choice solution:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();
int percentage = 25; //Set this to whatever percentage you want.

public void onCreatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent e) {
  //This will generate a number between 0 and 99 (inclusive)
  int generatedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);

  //If the generated number is smaller than the percentage you chose, you have "success".
  if(generatedNumber < percentage){
    addCharacteristic(creature, characteristic);
  }else{
    //Do whatever you need to normally.
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need. I have no idea why other people would downvote my question, but thanks for the answer. I was trying to use a count and other things that really did not work out.

Comment: I think the phrasing of your question was a little vague, but if you're not exactly sure what you're looking for, I don't think you should be penalized for that. I'll try to improve the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, when you are done, i will try to add more improvements to help anyone else that would need to look at this question.